# podman-compose: Run Services in Specific Order

Tags: podman, podman-compose

Is there a way to enforce starting services in a specific order? I am trying to do the following:

1. Start Azure SQL Edge service
2. Run SQL scripts to create database, schema, and tables (using mssql-tools image + `sqlcmd`)
3. Run a .net core app that processes SQL scripts to create/load data

I can get (1) and (2) working by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846535/21494839) solution. However, when I add (3) it seems to be created/run immediately after (2) even if I use `depends_on: service_completed_successfully`.

I do not have control over the code in (3), so I cannot add wait checks in there that ensure the necessary database structure has been created.

It seems like podman-compose does not treat `depends_on: service_completed_successfully` the same way that docker-compose does. I tried creating a compose file that just runs two shell scripts in order, and they both kick off at the same time despite setting one with a `depends_on` the other.